# Como obtener un item de un ArrayList?

Tags: android, arraylist

el problema que tengo es al tratar de recuperar un `item` de un `ArrayList` que llene con datos desde **Mysql**, ya que cuando intento obtenerlo con el `get()` me dice lo sigiente:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference

**Metodo CargarSpinner:**

```
 public void CargarSpinner(JSONArray jsonArray){
    ListaSpinner = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        try {
            JSONObject hijo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ListaPadres.add(hijo.getString("email_padre"));
            ListaSpinner.add(hijo.getString("nombre_hijo"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ListaSpinner);
    estudiantes.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

**Aqui es donde intento obtener el item del ListArray:**

```
estudiantes = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_estudiantes);
    estudiantes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), estudiantes.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String email_padre = ListaSpinner.get(0).toString(); //Aqui es
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Lo que estoy haciendo es utilizar un `ArrayList` para llenar el `Spinner` con los nombres y el otro `ArrayList` para guardar sus email, pero ya probe de obtner un item de ambas listas pero se detiene la aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de `onItemSelected()` puedes obtener un objeto, y obtener su valor:

```
Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String email_padre = item.toString();
```

Este sería el código :

```
estudiantes = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_estudiantes);
    estudiantes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), estudiantes.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String email_padre = item.toString();        
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

---

También puedes usar la variable `position` para obtener el valor dentro del list:

```
estudiantes = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_estudiantes);
    estudiantes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String email_padre = ListaSpinner.get(position).toString();            
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, y lo mismo seria para el otro ArrayList?

Comment: Veo que tratas de usar el List ListaSpinner pero en realidad este tiene valor null!, lo que debes realizar es asegurar enviar el List cuando creas el Adapter, revisa esta actualización.

Comment: Ahhh ya, si tienes razón, estoy tratando de obtener el `ìtem` sin aún haber obtenido los datos, es por eso que me muestra vacio. Gracias @Jorgesys.